# Windows Live Mail from Outlook Express?

Tags: windows-live-mail, outlook-express

Is there any way to access Windows Live Mail from Outlook Express?  Microsoft recommends downloading the Windows Live Mail client, but I don't want to install it unless I absolutely have to.  I would love to be able to continue to pull my Hotmail from Outlook Express.

Edit: Although I marked the POP3 method as the answer, I've decided to go with the Windows Live Mail client.  From everything I've read, I really don't see a downside to upgrading from Outlook Express.

Comment: Why don't you want to install it?

Comment: Personally, I like Live Mail; I'm currently using it on Windows 7.  However, the user I'm helping would prefer to stick with what she's already using (Outlook Express 7 on XP).

Comment: This says it all: "Mail combines the ease of use of Outlook Express, with the speed of Windows Live." - Source: http://download.live.com/wlmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article shows how to connect Outlook Express to your Hotmail account using POP3.](http://windowslivehelp.com/solutions/settings/archive/2009/02/18/how-to-add-your-e-mail-account-to-microsoft-outlook-express.aspx)

Comment: This may be my best option for sticking with Outlook Express.  However, Microsoft mentions the following:
"NOTE: If you are moving from DAV to POP3, there are a few important differences. With POP3, there is no synchronizing. For example, if you read an e-mail message in Outlook Express the message will be unread if you view your Hotmail account on the web. Also, only messages in your Hotmail Inbox will display in Outlook Express. Other folders, and any messages in them, will not be displayed."  
It's too bad they removed the ability to synchronize with OE. :(

Comment: The no synchronising is bad but I guess that is a limitation of the POP3 protocol.  BTW - Why are you so against Windows Live Mail client?  I use GMail personally, but my wife has the Windows Live Mail Client and she seems to like and as far as I can tell it seems a lot like OE.

Answer (score 1):

You will absolutely have to, Outlook Express is getting deprecated and there is no support for Windows Live synchronisation whatsoever. Just download and use it, you won't regret it!

Comment: I tend to agree with you, TomWij, but Dave Webb's post does answer the question -- if somewhat imperfectly. There is a way, but it does not, as you said, provide synchronization. I will ultimately have the user upgrade to the Windows Live client and then tweak it to look and behave more like Outlook Express, so it's not such a jarring change. (I'd upvote your answer if I could.)

Comment: Finally got enough rep to upvote! =)

Answer (score 0):

Download [Microsoft Office Outlook Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9A2279B1-DF0A-46E1-AA93-7D4870871ECF&displaylang=en) and install it.
I think it should do what you want.

Comment: No, it's designed for Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007.